# Dart wrapper library for the new Firebase version ^4.0.0 error

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, angular-dart, dart-pub

Dart wrapper library for the new Firebase.
I have updated the firebase dependency in my AngularDart project from version ^3.0.0 to ^4.0.0, but it's showing an error: **Undefined class'fb.AuthEvent'.**`

firebase_service.dart

```
  import 'dart:async';
  import 'package:angular2/core.dart';
  import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;
  import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';

@Injectable()
  class FirebaseService {
  fb.User user;
  fb.Auth _fbAuth;
  fb.GoogleAuthProvider _fbGoogleAuthProvider;
  fb.Database _fbDatabase;
  fb.Storage _fbStorage;
  fb.DatabaseReference _fbRefMessages;

 FirebaseService() {
   fb.initializeApp(
   apiKey: ".......",
   authDomain: ".....",
   databaseURL: ".....",
   storageBucket: ".....",
 );

_fbGoogleAuthProvider = new fb.GoogleAuthProvider();
_fbAuth = fb.auth();
_fbAuth.onAuthStateChanged.listen(_authChanged);
}

void _authChanged(fb.AuthEvent event) {
 user = event.user;
}

Future signIn() async {
  try {
   await _fbAuth.signInWithPopup(_fbGoogleAuthProvider);
 }
 catch (error) {
  print("$runtimeType::login() -- $error");
  }
}

 void signOut() {
  _fbAuth.signOut();
  }
 }`
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Firebase package [Changelog](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase#pub-pkg-tab-changelog)

```
Breaking changes

- The value in Auth.onAuthStateChanged is now User. AuthEvent has been 
removed.
```

And from the new [Documentation](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/firebase/4.0.0/firebase/Auth-class.html), `onAuthStateChanged` is a `Stream<User>`

So you should change your `_authChanged` function to

```
void _authChanged(fb.User event) {
   user = event;
}
```